# Interpretation of fractional $(l,m)$ in $\mathbf{L} = \mathbf{x} \times \mathbf{p}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

I am reading *Modern Quantum Mechanics* by Sakurai. In the section of Angular Momentum the author shows the eigenvalues of $L_z$ are half-integers at worst if $L_j$ are generators of rotations. This prompts me to think about *fractional* spherical harmonic
$$Y^{1/2}_{1/2}(\theta,\phi) = c_{1/2}e^{i\phi/2}\sqrt{\sin\theta}$$
Nominally it is both the eigenfunction of $\mathbf{L}^2$ and $L_z$ for $\mathbf{L} = \mathbf{x}\times \mathbf{p}$ (one could plug $Y^{1/2}_{1/2}(\theta,\phi)$ into $\mathbf{L}^2$, $L_z$ and check).   However, it is not a function at all since it changes sign after a $2\pi$ rotation so it cannot be a wave function on $\mathbf{R}^3$. Nevertheless, this behavior reminds me the branch point in complex analysis. Is there any meaningful interpretations of $Y^{1/2}_{1/2}(\theta,\phi)$ in physics?

Comment: Imposing a monodromy condition on $\phi$-angular part of spherical harmonics you get that $m$ is an integer value.

Comment: To get half-integral eigenvalues for $L_z$ you need to act on even-dimensional spinors with matrices of that size; it is impossible to use plain differential operators. You then see the eigenfunctions in the spinors depend on φ/2,  not just φ. Your proposed spherical harmonic is not terribly meaningful...